# Is it possible to create trigger for "after connect" in oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers, connection-string

I am trying to do execute a trigger whenever a `connect user/pass` is executed in Oracle.

Tried with following `after logon` trigger, but it didn't execute:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logon_trigger
  AFTER LOGON
  ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Logon detected');
END;
/
```

After creating the above trigger, tried the following connect operation but it didn't succeed:

```
conn scott/tiger@pdb1
conn system/manager@pdb1
```

Searched in AskTom and other Oracle related Q&A sites, but didn't get any right pointers to implement this. It would be great is someone can point out a right way to achieve this.

Comment: Connecting resets `serveroutput` to off (in SQL\*Plus); who do you expect to see the output? The connecting user already knows they have connected. The trigger is firing if you intend to do something more meaningful and just did this as a simple test though.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you for making me understand reset of serveroutput setting. When i tried some other table related operation instead of `dbms_output` it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Your code as written would not succeed because the DBMS_OUTPUT would not be visible to you. It defaults to server output: off on connect. (Thanks Alex) You need to write to a table, or even better, use the [built in Oracle auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG30002) that writes to SYS.AUD$

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET AUDIT_TRAIL=DB SCOPE=SPFILE;

AUDIT ALL BY Your_User BY ACCESS;
```

Or just the basic access

```
  AUDIT SESSION;
```