# How can I find the source of "empty" trigger entry during cx_Oracle.connect? ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '.'

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am trying to get TCP**S** connection to DB from python.

The conenction with TCP with same code/files/credentials works OK

When I update tnsnames.ora file to have `PROTOCOL=TCPS` I get the following:

**EDIT**: I also change the **port** for the connection

The code I am running:

```
connection_string = user + "/" + password + "@" + tns
cx_Oracle.connect(connection_string, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

`

The error I get on the **cx_Oracle.connect** line:

`ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '.'`

- This is the only ORA-* error I get.
- cswallet/ewallet files has 644
- sqlnet.ora is in $TNS_ADMIN path and points to the correct wallet folder with cswallet.sso and ewallet.p12

  - SSL_VERSION=1.2
  - SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
  - WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = <FULL_PATH>/wallet)))
- Oracle versions used: 19.12 & 21.9 with same output for both TCP/TCPS scenarios

Questions:

- how can I find the source of this `'.'` trigger?
- Does connection_string get empty for some reason with TCP**S** type of protocol?
- Does connection_string in cx_Oracle.connect considered to be a trigger as well?

Comment: you have a logon trigger like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017219/is-it-possible-to-create-trigger-for-after-connect-in-oracle  you can search for it like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896621/oracle-sql-query-to-find-all-the-triggers-belonging-to-the-tables